# How can i save to clipboard an image in base64?

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard, maui

I'm trying to save to clipboard an image in base64. But i can't find methods to do it. I can get the base64 string and save it, but not an Image :

```
public void GetUrl(ExportEventArgs Args) 
    { 
        string dataURL = Args.DataUrl;
        //byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dataURL);  

        //System.Drawing.Image image;
        //using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        //{
        //    image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        //}
        Clipboard.SetTextAsync(dataURL);
    }
```

I'm using .NET MAUI Blazor and the Clipboard class is *Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard* but i can't find how do it.

Thanks :)

Comment: So what you are asking is how to convert the image to Base64, right?

Comment: I'm trying to save to clipboard an image initially in base64.

Comment: this is a 2-step process: 1) convert image to Base64, 2) assign to the cilpboard.  Which step are you having a problem with?

Comment: I have a problem with the second step, it seems that there's no method in class Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard which allow me to save an image to clipboard

Comment: it's not an image, it's a string.  That's the entire point of converting it to Base64

Comment: In the snippet i gave you, dataURL is a base64 string which represent the image i want to put in my clipboard. The commented code represent the conversion from base64 to System.Drawing.Image .